# Access services on the Google Cloud Build instance

Tags: google-cloud-build

As part of my build pipeline, I'm building and running a container on the GCB host.

For validation purposes, I'd like to access a service on net container (say, a HTTP server) from outside GCB (say, from a GCE instance). Is that possible at all?

Basically: is the GCB address reachable and is ingress networking allowed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an alpha product called "Custom Workers" which allows you to run builds on GCE instances you control. You can create ingress rules as necessary.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUKCbq1WNWc (skip to about 13:10)